# Windows 2003 dynamic ports rellocation

Tags: windows, networking, port, tcpip

After digging the internet for a way to relocate the dynamic ports
 
start number and range... I found the following registry settings...

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet (Key)
    \UseInternetPorts="Y" (REG_SZ)
    \PortsInternetAvailable="Y" (REG_SZ)
    \Ports 50000-65535 (REG_MULTI_SZ)
```

I add this setting to the registry and restarted the server...

In effect some applications get the dynamic port after the 50000 address

But to my surprise there a small  number of application still getting dynamic ports below 50000... like 1150, 1183 etc.

I verified the system and these are really dynamic ports...
They even close and reopen with a new number...
My only problem is that they aren't above the start value set at 50000...

?Any ideas ???

Comment: Note that end of life products are generally off-topic here at Server Fault.

Comment: Yet they're still used pervasively in all the world... and this will happen for quite some time from now... some of them will work until the end-of-life of the host equipment... so... let's solve the problem... and not avoid it !!!